# Using ViewBag properties for Html.Routelink link text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper, viewbag

Attempting to use `ViewBag` when calling `Html.RouteLink`:

```
@{                             
    <li>@Html.RouteLink("Inbox (" + ViewBag.NewMessageCount + ")", 
                          "ViewInbox", 
                          new { pseudoName = User.Identity.Name }) | </li>
}
```

This results in an error:

> System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' has no applicable method named 'RouteLink' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

How can you use a property on the `ViewBag` value in the Link Text?

Comment: Problem is that it gives me a compilation error right at this line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message tells you, you cannot use `dynamic` operations with extension methods.

Casting the `ViewBag.` expression to a non-`dynamic` type will fix the problem.

```
(string)(ViewBag.MyProperty)
```

Comment: Ok, I'm not always the best at understanding error messages but your answer helped me correct the issue. Thank you.